# How to check whether id value is already present in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check whether an object with a certain id property is already present in the array:

```
var items  =[{id:1,name:'ted'},{id:2,name:'john'}]
```

How can I do this with jquery or vanilla js in a compact way? I know I can just create a for loop but is there anything else you can use?

Comment: `item.find( s => s.id == idToBeCompared )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *array.prototype.some*:

```js
var items  =[{id:1,name:'ted'},{id:2,name:'john'},{id:3, name:'tod'}];
var id = 2;
var exists = items.some(item => item.id === id)
console.log(exists);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items  =[{id:1,name:'ted'},{id:2,name:'john'},{id:3, name:'tod'}];
var id = 2;
var checkid = false;
for(var i =0; i<items.length; i++){  
    if(items[i].id ==id) //this condition check if id exists or not)
      checkid=true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :-) Please read [answer]. Code-only answers aren't useful to the community

Comment: Adding to what Jim said, this answer, if it works, is useful _if_ you add some explanation to it. Please edit the question and add some.